# Error: "The name '(variable)' does not exist in the current context"

Tags: c#

Creating a new instance of `Cost`:

```
Cost newCost = new Cost();

newCost.TotalCost = 0;
newCost.Event = 1000;
newCost.personalEvent = 1500;
newCost.organisationalEvent = 1700;
```

then the `if` statement below it:

```
if (EventList.SelectedItem == "Event")
{
    TotalCost = (Event + 100);
}
else if (EventList.SelectedItem == "Personal")
{
    TotalCost = (personalEvent + 150);
}

else if (EventList.SelectedItem == "Organisational")
{
    TotalCost = (organisationalEvent + 170);
}
else
{
    txtTotalCost.Text = ("£" + TotalCost.ToString());
}
```

I also have a class named `Cost`, but i keep getting an error saying `"The name 'TotalCost' does not exist in the current context"`.

Any help would be really appreciated.

My `Cost` class is as follows:

```
class Cost
{
    public int TotalCost;
    public int Event;
    public int personalEvent;
    public int organisationalEvent;
}
```

Comment: You haven't defined `TotalCost` in your code. do you mean to access `newCost.TotalCost` ?

Comment: Do you mean to say `newCost.TotalCost` instead of just `TotalCost`?

Comment: Is the logic of if-else is part of your `Cost` class?

Comment: @Csharpie Just edit your post with the complete, relevant code. Comments don't offer formatting and are very limited in length.

Comment: I have added the code within my cost class

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to access the `TotalCost` field in your class, you need to provide an instance reference so that the computer knows from what object to read the value.

**Replace `TotalCost` in the code with `newCost.TotalCost`.**

```cs
if (EventList.SelectedItem == "Event")
{
    newCost.TotalCost = (Event + 100);
}
else if (EventList.SelectedItem == "Personal")
{
    newCost.TotalCost = (personalEvent + 150);
}
else if (EventList.SelectedItem == "Organisational")
{
    newCost.TotalCost = (organisationalEvent + 170);
}
else
{
    txtTotalCost.Text = ("£" + newCost.TotalCost.ToString());
}
```

By the way, it's not clear to me why you set `txtTotalCost.Text` only if you have *not* set the `TotalCost` field value. I would expect at a minimum that it's when you *do* set the `TotalCost` field value that you would want to update the `txtTotalCost.Text` property, and probably it makes sense to just always set it.